# How to compare different values in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

I must to check if two values, X and Y are different. If both are null, they must be considered as equal.

The unique way I found is:

```
select 1 as valueExists 
where  (@X is null and @Y is not null) 
    or (@Y is null and @X is not null) 
    or (@X <> @Y)
```

Is there a smart way to write this expression?
Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT 1 as valuesDifferent WHERE EXISTS (SELECT @X EXCEPT SELECT @Y)`. The answer you accepted doesn't work correctly for `SET @X = ''; SET @Y = NULL`

Comment: @Martin Smith could you explain what your code does please?

Comment: `where exists` returns true if the sub query it contains returns a row. This will happen in this case if the two values are distinct. Treating `null` as a distinct value

Comment: @MartinSmith That duplicate is not the same question and the answer in the duplicate is not the same answer you post in comment.  I suggest you post that as an answer.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: Well actually the answer is basically the same. Maybe not the question then!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL`

```
WHERE ISNULL(@X,'') <> ISNULL(@Y,'')
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use COALESCE for that

```
WHERE coalesce(@X, '') <> coalesce(@Y, '')
```

What it does it returns an empty string if one of variables is `null`, so if two variables are `null` the two empty strings become equal.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use a technique I picked up [from here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx)

```
SELECT 1 AS valuesDifferent
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT @X
               EXCEPT
               SELECT @Y)
```

`WHERE  EXISTS` returns true if the sub query it contains returns a row. This will happen in this case if the two values are distinct. null is treated as a distinct value for the purposes of this operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [NULLIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) like this:

```
WHERE NULLIF(@X,@Y) IS NOT NULL OR NULLIF(@Y,@X) IS NOT NULL
```